# How to get destination from disconnect message?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, stomp

I have a WebSocket app on Spring Boot. I use STOMP, and I need to get destination path when user close the tab(disconnect from WS). I intercept the disconnect either with `@EventListener` or extends from `ChannelInterceptor` and override `preSend()`.

I tried many ways - `StompHeaderAccessor.getDestination()`, `SessionDisconnectEvent.getMessage().getHeaders().get("simpDestination")`, etc, but they all return null. Is there a working way to get the path? Maybe not using interceptors, somehow differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to Spring specifics, but I don't think the information you want is available from a Stomp perspective. As noted in the [Stomp 1.2 specification](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#DISCONNECT), the `DISCONNECT` frame doesn't use any kind of destination header. The only possible header is `receipt`. The semantics of receipts are explained [here](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#RECEIPT).